# How to hide links from ui-grid after click in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Using Angular-UI-Grid... I have the following data (paginated):

Name | Link
A | Show Hide
B | Show Hide

```
In my options:
cellTemplate:'<div>' +
               '  <a ng-click="grid.appScope.show(row)">Show</a> <a ng-click="grid.appScope.hide(row)">Hide' +'</div>' }
```

How can I make it such that if I click "Show", hide is displayed for that specific row. If I click "Hide", then "Show" is displayed for that specific row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a boolean to keep track of what is being shown.
Then in your methods invert your boolean.

As an example:

```
   $scope.isShowing = true;
```

Then modify your anchors.

```
 <a ng-hide="isShowing" ng-click="grid.appScope.show(row)">Show</a>
```

and

```
<a ng-show="isShowing" ng-click="grid.appScope.hide(row)">Hide' +'</div>'
```

and in your show/hide methods

```
$scope.isShowing = !$scope.isShowing
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ashley Kurkowski in Angular ui-grid you wont have access to `isShowing` in your `appScopeProvider` scope. But with a slight adjustment your approach is correct.

```
cellTemplate: '<div><a ng-show="showRow" ng-click="grid.appScope.show(row); showRow = !showRow;">Show</a> <a ng-show="!showRow" ng-click="grid.appScope.show(row); showRow = !showRow;">Hide</a></div>'
```

I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdqb4JM34Qu2EQye01MV?p=preview) for that.